# Array of positive integers , ideas for efficient implementation

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a small problem within a bigger problem.

I have an array of positive integers. I need to find a position i in the array such that all the numbers which are smaller than the element at position i should appear after it.

Example:

(let's assume array is indexed at 1)

2, 3, 4, 1, 9,3, 2 => 3rd pos  // 1,2,3 are less than 4 and are occurring after it.

5, 2, 1, 5  =>  2nd pos

1,2,1 => 2nd pos

1, 4, 6, 7, 2, 3 => doesn't exist

I'm thinking of using a hashtable but I don't know exactly how. Or sorting would be better? Any ideas for an efficient idea?

Comment: I edited the question, s.t.= such that :)

Comment: are you using a specific language?

Comment: I'll implement in Python. It doesn't matter much actually, I'm rather after a good algorithm.

Comment: Sorting seems out of the question. Try building two lists, from left-to-right and right-to-left. As long as you are not in the middle and the lists are equal, you're good.

Comment: What would be the expected result from a set "1,1,2,2"?

Comment: It's not indeed, sorry for inconvenience. I edited the question.

Comment: @Peter it's -1. Such position doesn't exists in 1,1,2,2.

Comment: Are you looking for a function with a single input of "array" and the output being the first position in the array where a number before that position appears after that position or false if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, I'll take an array as input. I'll output if such position exists, else I'll return -1. Every number before that position should exists after that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can start by creating a map (or hash table or whatever), which records the last occurence for each entry:

```
for i from 1 to n
    lastOccurrence[arr[i]] = i
next
```

We know that if `j` is a valid answer, then every number smaller than `j` is also a valid answer. So we want to find the maximum `j`. The minimum `j` is obviously `1` because then the left sublist is empty.

We can then iterate all possible `j`s and check their validity.

```
maxJ = n
for j from 1 to n
    if j > maxJ
        return maxJ
    if lastOccurrence[arr[j]] == j
        return j
    maxJ = min(maxJ, lastOccurrence[arr[j]] - 1)
next
```

Comment: Regarding your first `if`: if `maxJ` starts out as `n` and according to the last line can only get smaller than its starting value, can `j` actually end up larger?

Comment: @Jongware Yes, in the example `{2, 3, 2, 2, 3}`. `j` goes up to 4 but `maxJ` is 3.

Comment: But in the above case, solution does not exist although maxJ is 3. Isn't the solution incorrect.

Comment: @rakesh: The correct solution for the case is 2. All items of the left sublist (2) are in the right sublist (2, 2, 3).

Answer (score 0):

```
from sets import Set
def findMaxIndex(array):
    lastSet = Set()
    size = len(array)
    maxIndex = size
    for index in range(size-1,-1,-1):
        if array[index] in lastSet:
            continue
        else:
            lastSet.add(array[index])
            maxIndex = index + 1
    if maxIndex == 1:
        return 0 # don't exist
    else:
        return maxIndex
```

from the last element to the first, use a `set` to keep elements having met, if iterate element(index `i`) is not in `set`, then the max index is `i`, and update the `set`